# React change structure of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to change array structure from api but i don't know how.

First array:

```
const from = [
  {
    country: 'Country1',
    items: [
      {
        name: 'A name',
      },
      {
        name: 'B name',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    country: 'Country2',
    items: [
      {
        name: 'A name',
      },
      {
        name: 'B name',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I want this:

```
const to = [
  {
    country: 'Country1',
    letters: [
      { letter: 'A', items: [{ name: 'A name' }] },
      { letter: 'B', items: [{ name: 'B name' }] },
    ],
  },
  {
    country: 'Country2',
    letters: [
      { letter: 'A', items: [{ name: 'A name' }] },
      { letter: 'B', items: [{ name: 'B name' }] },
    ],
  },
];
```

I created alphabetic array in my code and try to map new array starting from letters but results is wrong.
Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate the array with `Array.map()`. To create the `letters` array, reduce the `items` array to an object, using the first letters as keys (`letter`). If the current letter object doesn't exist, create it. Push the current item to the letter's `items` array.

```js
const fn = arr =>
  // iterate the array
  arr.map(({ items, ...rest }) => ({ // create the object by extracting the items, and spreading the other propteries
    ...rest,
    // reduce the items to group by letter, and convert to array
    letters: Object.values(items.reduce((acc, { name }) => {
      const letter = name.replace(/\s.*$/, ''); // get the letter by removing the resting of the string
      
      // add the letter to the object if it doesn't exist
      if(!(letter in acc)) acc[letter] = { letter, items: [] };
      
      // push the current item to the letter's items
      acc[letter].items.push({ name });

      return acc;
    }, {}))
  }));

const from = [{"country":"Country1","items":[{"name":"A name"},{"name":"B name"}]},{"country":"Country2","items":[{"name":"A name"},{"name":"B name"}]}];

const result = fn(from);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant way:

```
const to = from.map(obj => {
    const newObj = {
        country: obj.country,
    };
    newObj.letters = obj.items.map(item => {
             const letterObj = {};
             letterObj.letter = item.split(" ")[0];
             letterObj.items = [item];
             return letterObj;
    })
   return newObj;
})
```